# How can I remove this Bar in "fullscreenmode"?

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen

My Problem is that there's a little bar at the top of my screen which i want to remove (I want the picture to be fullscreen). I'm not sure though from which source this bar is caused.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKWw0.jpg)

Here's my code till now:

```
    lpane = new JLayeredPane();
    lpane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panelBlue = new JPanel();
    panelGreen = new JPanel();
    frame.add(lpane);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    lpane.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    BufferedImage background = null;
    BufferedImage title = null;
    try{
        background = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/background.jpg"));
    }catch(IOException ex){
        sendErrorMessage("Picture couldn't be loaded"); //custom Errormessage Method
    }
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(background));
    ImageIcon buttonbackground = new ImageIcon(flames);
    panelBlue.add(picLabel);
    panelBlue.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    panelBlue.setOpaque(true);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

I'm not sure if the cause is the JLabel or if it has something to do with the undecorated frame.

What's the cause and how can i remove the bar?
Thx in advance

Comment: Try removing your content pane to check if it disappears. It may be some `JLabel` or other `JComponent` that you added to the frame, with slightly broken layout.

Comment: caused by panelBlue.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);

Comment: is there reason to use JLayeredPane instead of JPanel, don't to use NullLayout

Comment: I want to add an other panel on top of the background at a later time and i was told i should use LayeredPane for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `setBounds`. This is just plain wrong. The proper way is to use an appropriate `LayoutManager`. Additionaly, if you use `pack()`, using `setBounds` before is useless.

To put you frame in fullscreen, you can use any of the following:

- `frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() & JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`
- `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(frame);`

See this example that illustrates this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFullScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestFullScreen().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        private ImageIcon imageIcon;

        public ImagePanel(ImageIcon imageIcon) {
            super();
            this.imageIcon = imageIcon;
        };

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(imageIcon.getIconWidth(), imageIcon.getIconHeight());
        }

    }

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://blog.timesunion.com/opinion/files/2011/10/brickwall.jpg"))));
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() & JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        // GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: With the use of that ImagePanel the Bar dissaperad. I still don't know what caused it but thx.